# Apply boot::inv.logit() to a raster in R

Tags: r, raster, logistic-regression, r-raster

I have a `Formal Class Raster` and I am trying to apply the **boot::inv.logit()** function to its raster cells, for example:

```
r1 <- raster(nrows=25, ncols=25, vals=rtnorm(n = 625, .1, .9))
r2 <- boot::inv.logit(r1)
```

However, when I try that, it retruns an error:

```
> Error in plogis(x) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

If I turn the raster into a matrix, and then back to raster, it gets the job done, but I loose all the other info associated with the "Formal Class Raster" I had at the beginning, which is not ideal:

```
r2 <- boot::inv.logit(as.matrix(r1))
r2 <- as.raster(r2)
```

Is there an easy way to either recover the `Formal Class Raster` info I had before or apply the `inv.logit()` to the raster without the `as.matrix()` transformation? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the function to the raster, use the `calc` method from `raster`:

```
r2 <- calc(r1,boot::inv.logit)

> r2 

# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 25, 25, 625  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 14.4, 7.2  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 0.07434905, 0.9498965  (min, max)
```

Alternatively, you can make an empty copy of `r1`, and just fill in the values coming out of `inv.logit`:

```
r2 <- raster(r1)
r2[] <- boot::inv.logit(as.matrix(r1))
```